# When the associated bundle to a $U(1)$-bundle is an holomorphic line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $P$ be a principal $U(1)$ bundle over a complex manifold $M$, and let $\rho\colon U(1)\to Aut(\mathbb{C})$ be the representation of $U(1)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ given by the standard multiplication. My question is: when is the complex, rank-one, vector bundle $L = P\times_{\rho} \mathbb{C}$ associated to $P$ an holomorphic line bundle? Or in other words: what conditions do the local transition functions of $P$ have to satisfy in order for $L$ to be an holomorphic line bundle?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by principal bundle over a complex manifold. The trivializations are via an isomorphism in what category (complex manifolds?)?

Comment: @user40276: I mean that the base is a complex manifold. The trivializations are smooth functions from the double overlaps to $U(1)$. In fact, what I am asking is what these transitions functions must satisfy in order for $L$ to be an holomorphic line bundle.